# Laravel 419 Page Expired on Form Submission

Tags: laravel, csrf, laravel-8

In Laravel 8, I'm getting a 419 | Page Expired error whenever I try submitting my form. I made sure to include the CSRF token using the Blade Directive @csrf. For debugging simplicity, I reduced my form to:

```
<form id="form-contact" name="form-contact" class="contact-form" method="POST">
    @csrf

    <div class="row"> 
        <div class="col-sm-6 animated">
            <div class="input-text form-group">
                <input type="text" name="name" id="name" class="input-name form-control" placeholder="Full Name*" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <button class="btn btn-sm active" type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

And I'm still getting a 419 page expired error.

In my .env file:

```
SESSION_DRIVER=file
SESSION_LIFETIME=120
```

On the command line, if I check my sessions folder permissions:

```
ls -ld storage/framework/sessions
```

I get:

```
drwxrwsr-x 2 apache www 12288 Oct  1 15:32 storage/framework/sessions
```

Are those permissions correct for the sessions directory, or do I need to change the permissions?

Is there anything else I might need to do to fix this 419 problem?

Comment: Try clearing your cache - php artisan cache:clear

Comment: I tried that, didn't work.

Comment: You are submitting a POST to the current route. Does the request get to the controller method or it fails with 419 before?

Comment: It fails with a 419 before reaching the controller method.

Comment: Try SESSION_SECURE_COOKIE=false in your .env for development.

Comment: This app is running on a production server with HTTPS. I tried SESSION_SECURE_COOKIE=false to no avail.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/222390/discussion-between-gts-joe-and-guizo).

Comment: @GTSJoe can you please put your jQuery code as well

Comment: pass csrf token in your jquery code,

Comment: I'm not using jQuery to submit my form, just a regular HTML form submission. No JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error as yours.

```
<form id="form-contact" name="form-contact" class="contact-form" method="get">
```

and change your route to get router: Route::get();

I am sure it will work!!

Comment: why does method="post" not work?